# Laravel collection intersect on nested object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I've two collections given below:

```php
$collection1 = collect([
    [13254, 28.2],
    [13332, 23.45],
]);

$collection2 = collect([
    [14673, 14.2],
    [13254, 12.2],
]);
```

And I expect the output similar to:

```php
[
    [13254, 28.2],
]
```

I tried using `$collection1->intersect($collection2)` but that did not seem to work.

Comment: having a hard time understanding the goal. Why specifically should that be the array that is returned? under what parameters?

Comment: @RawSlugs That doesn't need to be an array. For the sake of example, I just put array there. Main goal is to get a collection of nested arrays that exists in both of the collections.

Comment: so basically given any two collections, you want all arrays from both collections as one collection? (assuming the collections can have values other than arrays) or are you trying to get the nested arrays compared to the nested arrays in the other collection?

Comment: How many numbers can be here? `[13254, 28.2]`  Only two or a lot?

Answer (score 0):

try this code just i use **map**

```
$res =  $collectionA->map(function ($item ,$index) use ($collectionB){

        if( (($item[0] == $collectionB[$index][0]) || ($item[1] == $collectionB[$index][1]) ){
            return $item;
        }

    })->filter();
```